# How to fix "The project is not a Gradle-based project " error while importing a project?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have currently started learning android studio through google and in one chapter I was provided with the source code of the app on which I have to perform Intends but when I imported the app the following errors are occurring. The link of the project file is as follow:
https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-basics-kotlin-words-app
The screenshot of the error is as follows.
[Error Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWQ1U.png)

and when I tried to SYNC Project with Gradle file the following error appeared.
[error image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1iGn.png)
Kindly help me as I tried my best to solve this issue.